# Is Linq to Sql DeleteOnSubmit threadsafe?

Tags: multithreading, linq-to-sql, thread-safety

Assuming the decision to delete is independent and threadsafe, is it threadsafe to call [DeleteOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763473%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in parallel?

All entities will be added to the delete in parallel, then the change will be submitted afterwards.

My testing hasn't shown a problem, but that doesn't inherently mean it's safe....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

LINQ to SQL itself is not thread-safe; nor are any of its methods.

Comment: Do you have a link describing this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/3ae5e457-099e-4d13-9a8b-df3ed4ba0bab/ http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/29/linq-to-sql-the-multi-tier-story/

Comment: I see that the datacontext is not threadsafe as a whole, because many things can be called from it. That doesn't mean that adding to the deletion list isn't threadsafe... does it?

Comment: I highly doubt that it's thread-safe.  Thread safe code does not happen by accident; it requires careful design and compromises.  For example, what if the list resizes?